# Skip element in XSLT if output already contains similar element

Tags: xslt

Say I have some XML like this (everything below has been trimmed down to try to show the minimum amount needed to showcase my issue).

```
<Person>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
    <GroupID>123</GroupID>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Doug</Name>
    <GroupID>123</GroupID>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Melinda</Name>
    <GroupID>123</GroupID>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Kathy</Name>
    <GroupID>22</GroupID>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Mark</Name>
    <GroupID>22</GroupID>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Roberto</Name>
    <GroupID>33</GroupID>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Carlos</Name>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Sasha</Name>
</Person>
```

I want to be able to group these records by their GroupIDs, so the output should be something like:

```
<Persons>
    <Group>
        <GroupID>123</GroupID>
        <Person>
            <Name>Bob</Name>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <Name>Doug</Name>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <Name>Melinda</Name>
        </Person>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <GroupID>22</GroupID>
        <Person>
            <Name>Kathy</Name>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <Name>Mark</Name>
        </Person>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <GroupID>33</GroupID>
        <Person>
            <Name>Roberto</Name>
        </Person>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Person>
            <Name>Carlos</Name>
        </Person>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Person>
            <Name>Sasha</Name>
        </Person>
    </Group>
</Persons>
```

What I'm doing is something like this:

```
 <Persons>
    <xsl:for-each select="Person">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="GroupID != ''">
                <xsl:variable name="groupId" select="GroupID"/>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="groupId"/>
                    </GroupID>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../Person[GroupID = groupId]">
                        <xsl:call-template name="PersonData"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Group>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Group>
                    <xsl:call-template name="PersonData"/>
                </Group>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Persons>
```

The issue is that each Group gets duplicated for as many Persons as there are in the group. What I'd really like to be able to do is to either check if I've processed the "current" GroupID already or not - that way I can say "ok, this GroupID has already been processed, so skip it".

EDIT: this is using XSLT 2 with Xalan, so actually XSLT 1.

EDIT2: It is possible that the GroupID attribute can be missing for one or more records. In those instances, those records should each get an individual Group with no GroupID present.

Comment: Which XSLT version and engine are you using?

Comment: This is not a good grouping method to begin with. If you're using XSLT 1.0, use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Otherwise use the [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping) instruction.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - ah, yeah the for-each-group is exactly what I'm looking for. I haven't done anything with XSLT in at least 8 years, so I'm super rusty :) I was just trying to hobble my way through it.

Comment: Looks like we're using Xalan, so think I need to roll with Muenchian grouping as the current-grouping-key() function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Persons>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//Person" group-by="GroupID">
                <Group>
                    <GroupID><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></GroupID>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <Person>
                            <Name><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></Name>
                        </Person>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Persons>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZd

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works if I set the engine to Saxon. Turns out that we're using Xalan in production, so it won't work there (I don't think), and I'll need to use the Muenchian grouping approach, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, Xalan is only XSLT-1.0 so you can't use xsl:for-each-group.

Comment: Accepting this because it solved my original question. I wound up having to use the Muenchian grouping approach due to the Xalan deal.